# Founding computers on networks running a process

Tags: c#, networking, process

I am trying to find computer on a local network that runs a specific process. For this I have the following functions :

```
private IPAddress GetLocalIP()
    {
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                return ip;
        }
        return IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    }

    private string GetFriendIP()
    {

        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip != localIP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(ip.ToString()));
                Process[] allProcs = Process.GetProcesses(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(ip.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(ip.ToString()));

                foreach (Process p in allProcs)
                {
                    if (p.ProcessName == "You'll Catch A virus")
                        return GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(ip.ToString()) + ": " + ip.ToString();
                }
            }


        }
        return "No PCs connected on network";
    }
```

This code shows the error `Couldn't connect to remote machine` at `Process.GetProcesses(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(ip.ToString()))`. Although if I change the condition to `ip == localIP` the error goes away and the function returns that no machine have been found. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/x8b2hzk8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this InvalidOperationException is triggered when the target pc is running XP, NT or 2000. Is that the case for you ? In that case, you can't use this method, which is declared not supported.

Otherwise, you may want to read the documentation on SecurityDemands, although related error doesn't seem to trigger the error message you got.

Comment: The computer is running Windows 8, so where can I read the security demands? Couldn't find on the link to MSDN.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
You should precise the exception type you got. Was it an InvalidOperation ?